# Проблема вывода в Python: не выводит сообщение, которое написано в самом конце функции

Tags: python, математика, численные-методы

Добрый день!

Пишу программу, которая бы решала нелинейное уравнение методом Ньютона(касательных). Проблема не в реализации данного метода, а в выводе данных.

Почему то не выводит сообщение, которое написано в самом конце функции: "Приближенное решение методом ньютона " + str(x1).

В чем может быть проблема?

Буду рад помощи, так как Python начал изучать недавно.

Вот сам код:

```
import numpy as np

a=3
b=20
A=4
eps=0.0000001
N=10
k=3

if a<0 and b<0:
    print('Ошибка')

def f(x):
    return (x**k-1)/(x-1) - A

def df(x):
    return (k*x**k)/(x*(x-1)) - (x**k-1)/((x-1)**2)

def d2f(x):
    return (k**2 * x**k)/((x-1)*x**2) - (2*k*x**k)/(x*(x-1)**2) - 
(k*x**k)/(x**2*(x-1))+(2*x**k-2)/((x-1)**3)



def newton(a,b,eps):
    n=0
    if f(a)*d2f(a)>0:
        x0=a
    else:
        x0=b

    while True and n<=N:
        x1=x0-(f(x0)/df(x0))
        if abs(x1-x0)<eps:
            return x1
        x0=x1
        n+=1
    print('Приближенное решение методом Ньютона '+str(b))  //Вот это сообщение не выводится
    print('Выполненное количество итераций '+str(n)) // И это

newton(a,b,eps)
```

Comment: `return x1` срабатывает раньше, поэтому до `print()` не доходит...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказано в комментарии, вы выходите из функции раньше, чем идут функции `print`.

Необходимо заменить выход из функции на выход из цикла, выполнить вывод значений, вернуть значение.

```
def newton(a, b, eps):
    n = 0
    if f(a) * d2f(a) > 0:
        x0 = a
    else:
        x0 = b

    while n <= N: # True тут было лишним (оно же ВСЕГДА истина)
        x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / df(x0))
        if abs(x1 - x0) < eps:
            break # выход из цикла (значение x1 останется в области видимости)
        x0 = x1
        n += 1

    print('Приближенное решение методом Ньютона', b)
    print('Выполненное количество итераций', n)
    # перевод чисел в строку, конкатенация с добавлением пробела выполняется автоматически при передаче нескольких аргументов

    return x1
```

Comment: А лучше принты вообще убрать из функции, ибо мало-ли кто ее переиспользовать будет. `return x1, n` сделать, а результат выводить после вызова функции

Comment: @suit вопрос не об этом.

Comment: @suit, такие сообщения, по-моему лучше оформлять как `logging` (можно выводить в консоль или файл и настраивать уровень детализации [DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR]...)

Comment: @MaxU, не соглашусь на счет именно этих сообщений. Логи это логи, а вывод количества итераций вполне может быть результатом, который потребитель ожидает получить не заглядывая в логи. В логи можно положить сообщения типа "iteration 1, do smth..."